# How to evaluate mathematical expressions in Firebird

Tags: firebird

I need a function for Firebird that evaluates a mathematical expression and gives me the result, I don't know if there is any, right now I'm using the foxpro eval () expression that allows me to do it, but I wanted to integrate all the calculations in the database and not have to do the calculation outside the database. This is for an app similar to a spreadsheet, in which the operator enters additions, subtractions, multiplications, etc. and the result has to be calculated.

Comment: it would be unwise to let user input into the database engine. It is on top of "don't do it" rules of thumb. https://www.bobby-tables.com  If you really want to destroy all your database because your user would have bad mood then read about `execute statement` or `execute block` commands. Also notice that in-SQL evaluations are very hard to debug. You would hardly ever get Excel-like step by step evaluation debug facility ,for example.

Answer (score 1):

Firebird itself has nothing like this built in other than executing queries, and using that to evaluate expressions would make you vulnerable to SQL injection.

In it's basic form, you could do something like:

```sql
create function eval (formula varchar(1000))
  returns double precision
as
  declare result double precision;
begin
  execute statement 'select (' || formula || ') from rdb$database' into result;
  return result;
end
```

You can then execute as:

```sql
select eval('1 + 1') from rdb$database;
```

However, given it's vulnerability to SQL injection (though this is partially mitigated by how `execute statement` works), I would not recommend doing this.

The alternative would be to write it yourself (possibly as an external engine/UDR). Or you would need to find (and possibly pay) a third-party for such a solution.